# What's it called? Leather square

Tags: materials, patch

I want to acquire a piece of black leather with "rings" in it - holes that have been reinforced with a steel ring like you might find on a tarp.

```
####################################
#O################################O#
####################################
#O################################O#
####################################
```

It would look like that. Like everything else in life, I'm sure I could find it online if I knew what it was called. When I search for 'leather piece with ring' I mostly just get keychains. Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange. You will probably have to supply a little bit more information regarding what you are looking for. Some important details would be: Size, Weight of Leather and whether the leather is re-enforced with multiple thicknesses and extra stitching in those areas. Do note as well that this question is dangerously close to a "shopping question" which would be off topic here.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I searched a bit and found that "eyelet" (generally the 1-piece) or "grommet" (generally the 2-piece) covers it all - i.e., once you know that, you can shop based on size, weight, thickness, etc. OP isn't asking for the shopping (brand, store, product), just to know the terms. On the other hand, you could argue it is off-topic because it is arts & crafts.

Comment: Not sure what size you need, or what the intended purpose is, but that looks like a slingshot pouch or maybe a shoulder strap pad.  Searching for those terms might turn up something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eyelets** or **grommets**

Sorry for a one-line answer, but that's all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Contact a local leatherworker, belt maker or luggage repair shop to get exactly what you need. A tourist area has craft-type shops, such as Granville Island in Vancouver, Canada.